# Vue JS ERROR Component template should contain exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

While working on a VueJS component, you face the following error in your browser console (or in your JS linter output):

Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

As explained, VueJS component templates can contain one and only one root node. This is correct:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is not:

```
<template>
  <div class="hola">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Fix
Wrap your html tags into one parent element:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="hola">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hello">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Going further
In some case, you cannot afford to add an extra parent element without breaking HTML structure. For instance, if your child component template replace several `<tr>` in a parent HTML table:

```
<template>
  <tr class="hola">
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="hello">
    ...
  </tr>
</template>
```

In this specific case, you need have two solutions:

use functional components ;
use Fragments (my favorite one)
Fragments let you group multiple children below a parent element without adding extra nodes to the DOM at render. There is a vue-fragment package you can install:

```
npm install vue-fragments // yarn add vue-fragments
```

While loading VueJS:

```
import { Plugin } from "vue-fragments"; Vue.use(Plugin);
```

Then in your component template:

```
<template>
  <v-fragment>
    <tr class="hola">
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr class="hello">
      ...
    </tr>
  <v-fragment>
</template>
```

Comment: If you're using **Vue3** then it's not a problem anymore, & for linting bypass you could do something like this: `"vetur.validation.template": false`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.